# Vagrant private network not working after second vm is started

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I've run into a bit of a problem with Vagrant. I recently decided I wanted to set up a separate development box for Python/Flask apart from my PHP box. I have both of them setup with Private Network Connectivity like so

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

I have one set to .10 and the other set to .11. However once I start one up and then start the other I cannot access either through a browser via their respective IP addresses. The only issue I could think of is one of the machines is owned by root so VirtualBox may try to start up two separate instances of the network.

Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: Can you verify both client machines actually have their private IP addresses assigned?

When you say "browser", do you mean a file browser or a web browser?

Comment: should work - are both VMs running ? if you run vagrant global-status you can see the 2 VMs up ? can you ssh into any of the 2 ?

Comment: Looks like it was where I was using sudo to start one of the machines. Migrated both to be owned by my user and everything works as expected.

Comment: I would be very interested in how you use `sudo` to boot a vagrant box - that right there is a red flag to me. If you post your `Vagrantfile`(s) that could be helpful.

Comment: @BrianMorton That's a long story of messed up permissions and a botched corporate linux install. Their solution for me to run just about anything was to use sudo -s.

Comment: @BrianMorton also I'm just using the default Vagrantfile for scotchbox.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some testing and I set up another virtual box under my user and started up both machines under my user and they worked fine. It must be a bug where the other machine is owned by root and I use sudo to start up the other machine.

I migrated the work I did in the root owned machine to a new machine that's set up under my user and everything is working fine now and I am able to access both through my web browser.